# Does using HTML list markup in a blog post have advantages to using a paragraph with a dash at the beginning?

Tags: seo, html

Inside the text of a blog post, I have a paragraph where I highlight some points. It is like a summary. Should I use ul li tags there? What is the best practice? Does it matter?

Is there any advantage to use ul li tags over just make a paragraph with a dash at the beginning?. It seems more work and I do not see the advantage.

```
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use whatever makes sense. You shouldn't be munging your content for SEO *ever*.

Comment: If you were writing this document in a word processor, how would you format it?

Comment: @w3dk: I write it first in Apple Pages and I just write a paragraph with a dash before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some advantages:

1. A list looks better.

   - It doesn't have to have extra space between each line.
   - The bullet can be customized using CSS
2. It works better for users.  When it is copied and pasted, the bullets are not part of the text, but rather part of the formatting

I [enable markdown](https://en.support.wordpress.com/markdown/) in my blog.  That seems the best of both worlds.   I get to compose in a format that is simple, but lists automatically get converted from dashed paragraphs to actual lists.

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm in using lists in articles or any text content for that matter. First of all, when you are writing anything, stop worrying about search engines, Try to think what a user would find better i.e. you need to have a user-first approach. So, if a list can make it easy for a user to consume the information then use it!

Comment: The seo was only one question, I had many others. In fact, I deleted the seo part because it seems you all only seem to pay attention to that.

Comment: My bad. About what is better list elements or dashes, definitely list elements are better.